# Rails - Strange characters pass through validation and break query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation, character-encoding

I copy-pasted a string into a form field and a *strange character* broke my MySql query.

I could force the error on the console this way (the weird character is in the middle of the two words "Invalid" and "Character", you can also copy-paste it):

```
> dog.name = "Invalid ​Character"
> dog.save # -> false
```

Which returns the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x8BCha...' for column 'name' at row 1: UPDATE `dogs` SET `name` = 'Invalid ​Character' WHERE `dogs`.`id` = 2227
```

It replaced the character by **'\xE2\x80\x8B'** as the error said.

Is there any validation that I could use to remove these kind of weird characters?

**Obs**: I also saw that

```
> "Invalid ​Character".unpack('U*')
```

Returns

```
[73, 110, 118, 97, 108, 105, 100, 32, 8203, 67, 104, 97, 114, 97, 99, 116, 101, 114]
```

The weird character must be the 8230 one.

**Obs2**: In my application.rb, I have: `config.encoding = "utf-8"`

**EDIT**

On my console, I got:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.charset # -> "utf8"
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.collation # -> "utf8_unicode_ci"
```

I also ran (on the `rails db` mySql console):

```
> SELECT table_collation FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'dogs';
```

and got `"utf8_unicode_ci"`

**EDIT2**

If I change the table's character set to utf8mb4 I don't get the error. But still, I have to filter those characters.

Comment: Who's generating a "zero width space" (e2808b)?

Comment: Yes, it is the same as &#8203; It was hidden among the other characters and broke the query. Any character that wasn't from Latin1 was breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

On the rails db MySql console, I used:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE dogs;
```

To find out that the charset for the table was **latin1**.

I just added a migration with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE dogs CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

And it started to work fine.

Comment: It's been quite some time and I still didn't find or get a better solution to my problem than this one. 
I Wish the one that downvoted could add to the discussion. ;)

Comment: You should not use utf8 in MySQL, but utf8mb4, that's why you were downvoted. You can find more on the reason why here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql

Comment: @Theemuts, thanks. That's simple then. I've updated it after reading your reference.